# Java Bit Operation on Long - Counting Set and Unset bits

Tags: java

I have a long number. Now what I want is following (given in pseudo code) ,

```
int cnt1 = 0 
int cnt2 = 0 

for each two bits of that long

       if the two bits == 11
            then cnt1++

       else
            cnt2++

    Print i and i+1 th bits are ... (example 00, 11 etc.) and cnt1 = ... and cnt2 = ...

(for example if number is three (representation "00 00 00 .... 11)" 
  it will give output cnt1 = 1 and cnt2 = 31)
```

Can anybody help me how to do that ?

Comment: @Jeffrey, with shift operators. But can't understand, how to solve the issue of left most 0 bits example "00 00..11"

Comment: @harold, I need to print for example ith and i+1 th bits are "this" and corresponding counts.

Comment: @Arpssss yes I saw that just now, nevermind that suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you want to use pairs of bits. Out of curiosity, why bit pairs?

Comment: A `long` has 64 bits so the total could be 63? Are you thinking of an `int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is keep shifting by 2 bits to the right at every iteration and do a bitwise and (&) operation with the number 3 (11 in binary):

```
long number;
int cnt1 = 0;
int cnt2 = 0;
long test = 3;
int counter = 0;    

while(counter < 64) { // we have 64 bits to inspect
    if((number & test) == 3) { // last 2 bits are 11
        cnt1++;
    } else { // last 2 bits are either 10, 01 or 00
        cnt2++;
    }          
    counter += 2;
    number = number >>> 2; // shift by 2 bits to the right
}
```

Comment: You could skip `counter` altogether by using `while(cnt1+cnt2 < 32)` loop condition.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is create a bit-mask and run it over your value, assuming this is homework I will only give some pointers:

- the bit-mask you already gave: `long mask = 0x03L;`
- to check every other 2 bits, shift your mask left 2 potisions
- you can use a for-loop to check the value until your mask has value 0
- use the bitwise-and operator `&` to check a value against a mask

If you put above hints into code, you will have your answer :-)

**Edit** now that the results are in, my solution would be:

```
long cnt1 = 0;
long cnt2 = 0;

for (long mask = 0x03; mask != 0; mask <<=2) {

    (mask == (value & mask)) ? cnt1++ : cnt2++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A short answer.

```
long num = ~0L;
int cnt1 = Long.bitCount(num & (num >>> 1) & 0x5555555555555555L);
System.out.println(cnt1);
int cnt2 = 32 - cnt1;
```

prints

```
32
```

Comment: No no, Peter. I need to know, what bits are in ith and i+1 th position means whether 11 or (10,00,01).

Comment: I got answer, 1 and 31. Should be correct because I looked for long.

Comment: What if `num = ~0`? instead of counting 32 pairs you count 63 :-)

Comment: @rsp Good example. Actually it counted 63, so I fixed it. ;)